# why does this regex not make special characters compulsary

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

> `(?=^.{7,14}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+}{&quot;:;'?\/&gt;.&lt;,])(?!.*\s).*$`

It's meant to match and enforce the following  password policy:

- One Capital
- One lower case
- One digit
- one special char i.e. @

However, it allows a password without any special chars.

Comment: sorry can someone explain this to me. Never understood regular expression really. they're necessary evil!

Comment: You need to use real chars instead of the entities, see https://regex101.com/r/TVPOCO/2. What are you trying to achieve? Please re-write the question to describe your real problem.

Comment: sorry but I have the question has been updated thats exactly what am trying to archive

Comment: Regarding the *One Capital One lower case One digit one special char i.e. @* - why do you have `(?!.*\s)` that disallows whitespace? Another point: where are you using the regex? Does it mean you are after [`^(?=.{7,14}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*"_+(){}":;'?\/><.,]).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/I9dNPZ/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the html entities inside the character class (a character class is a set of characters, you can't put strings inside), consequence, strings that contain q,u,o,t,e,g or l succeed.

Instead you can use:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!-@_{}])\S{7,14}$
```

(The character class for special characters is shorten using ranges and the ascii table)

Comment: Sorry. It's basically another one of my imfamous copy and paste fail! I copied it out of my web.config which xml based hence entites otherwise visual studio complains.

Comment: @Ageis: it's bad: 2 ave 3 pater

Comment: huh??? sorry didn't understand your comment. If you're saying it's bad what I di. I know because am lazy and it's Monday.

Comment: When you make something bad, to obtain absolution, christians must recite prayers ( ave = ave Maria..., pater = pater noster... )